# UIView xib in UIViewController loading issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have 3 `UIViews` (lets call them `HeaderView`, `MainView` and `FooterView`) with `UIButtons`, `Label`, etc which I have set up in their respective `xibs`. I have connected the elements through `IBOutlets` in the respective `.h` files. In each of the `.m` files' `drawRect`, I have written some set up instructions like setting the colour of the text, setting an image for the `UIButton`, etc.
I have a `UIViewController` which is presented from a button click event. In this `UIViewController`, I have called `loadNib` methods for the 3 `UIViews` with specified frame.

The issue I'm facing is that none of the elements are being shown, for example, for one of the `UIViews` (`HeaderView`), the `button` and `label` is shown (checked it through `ViewDebugging`) but the `images` or the `texts` aren't set for some reason.

I'm sorry if I have not explained it properly but I have tried calling `addSubview` and `bringSubviewToFront` for the `UIButton` and `Label` for the `UIViews` as well and it just doesn't show up. Any help would be great. If someone could even direct me in the right direction, that would be really helpful. I have been frustratingly stuck on this and am lost as to what I should do.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You must take into consideration when are you creating the views from the xibs and adding them to the view hierarchy.

Typically you must do something like:

```
@implementation MYViewController 
{
    UIView *_headerView;
    UIView *_mainView;
    UIView *_footerView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _headerView = [[[UINib nibWithNibName:@"HeaderView" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
    _mainView = [[[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
    _footerView = [[[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FooterView" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] firstObject];

    _headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _footerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:_headerView];
    [self.view addSubview:_mainView];
    [self.view addSubview:_footerView];

    // Set here autolayouts for _headerView, _mainView and _footerView
}
@end
```

Also, you could configure your views as IBOutlets and use the file owner of the xib to assign the views (by setting the file owner of each XIB of header, main and footer views as a MYViewController class and assigning the view to the corresponding file's owner IBOutlet property):

```
@implementation MYViewController 
{
    IBOutlet UIView *_headerView;
    IBOutlet UIView *_mainView;
    IBOutlet UIView *_footerView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[UINib nibWithNibName:@"HeaderView" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    [[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    [[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FooterView" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];

    _headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _footerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:_headerView];
    [self.view addSubview:_mainView];
    [self.view addSubview:_footerView];

    // Set here autolayouts for _headerView, _mainView and _footerView
}
```

@end

Also, check your autolayout/autoresize implementation and add some NSLog flags on your views (on the method `-awakeFromNib`) to check if the view is loaded or not.